# Azure Data Factory Exception while reading table from Synapse and using staging for Polybase

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I'm using Data Flow in Data Factory and I need to join a table from Synapse with my flow of data.
When I added the new source in Azure Data Flow I had to add a Staging linked service (as the label said: "For SQL DW, please specify a staging location for PolyBase.")

So I specified a path in Azure Data Lake Gen2 in which Polybase can create its tem dir.

Nevertheless I'm getting this error:

> 

{"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'keyMapCliente': shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'abfss://MyContainerName@mystorgaename.dfs.core.windows.net/Raw/Tmp/e3e71c102e0a46cea0b286f17cc5b945/' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.","Details":"shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE AS SELECT statement failed as the path name 'abfss://MyContainerName@mystorgaename.dfs.core.windows.net/Raw/Tmp/e3e71c102e0a46cea0b286f17cc5b945/' could not be used for export. Please ensure that the specified path is a directory which exists or can be created, and that files can be created in that directory.\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:262)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1632)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:872)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:767)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)\n\tat shaded.msdataflow.com.microsoft.sqlserver.jd"}

> 

The following are the Azure Data Flow Settings:

[image]

this the added source inside the data flow:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hi @Salvatore Nedia, Can you confirm if your storage account is enabled to access all networks? You can check in your storage account under `Security + networking -->Networking-->Firewalls and virtual networks-->Public network access-->Enabled from all networks`.

Comment: Hi @NiharikaMoola-MT and thanks for ur support, I cannot have access from all network but I have enabled the access for data factory and any component needed (hopefully)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproed and was able to enable stagging location as azure data lake Gen2 storage account for polybase and connected synapse table data successfully.

- Create your database scooped credentials with [azure storage account key as secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=dedicated#h-create-external-data-source-to-access-data-in-azure-storage-using-the-abfs-interface-1).
- Create an external data source and an external table with the scooped credentials created.

In Azure data factory:

Enable staging and connect to azure data lake Gen2 storage account with Account key authentication type.

[image]

In the data flow, connect your source to the synapse table and enable staging property in the source option

[image]